# number guessing function in python using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

*So ive been trying to create a program of number guessing using tkinter but it isn't working proper like after first attempt it shows 0 attempts while ive declared 3 im attaching the source code here for better understanding the problem i feel is that its not taking `attempts`as a global scope so its not being accessed by the other functions*

```
import random
from tkinter import *

random_number = random.randint(0, 999)

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
root.title("Number guessing game")
label_0 = Label(root, text="Number guessing game", width=20, font=("bold", 20))
label_0.place(x=90, y=53)

label_1 = Label(root, text="Enter number", width=20, font=("bold", 10))
label_1.place(x=80, y=150)
entry_1 = Entry(root)
entry_1.place(x=240, y=150)


def printAttempts(_attempts):
    attempt_string = "Attempt left: " + str(_attempts)
    label_attempt = Label(root,
                          text=attempt_string,
                          width=20,
                          font=("bold", 20))
    label_attempt.place(x=90, y=100)


printAttempts(3)


def printMessage(msg):
    _message = Label(root, text=msg, width=50, font=("bold", 10))
    _message.place(x=80, y=200)


def onSubmit():

    attempts = 3
    guessed_number = entry_1.get()
    guessed_number = int(guessed_number)

    while attempts != 0:
        if (guessed_number == random_number):
            printMessage("Horray you just got it Right!")
            attempts = 0
            break
        else:
            attempts -= 1
            printMessage("You got it wrong :(")
            if (guessed_number > random_number):
                printMessage("Your guess number is greater than lucky number")
            else:
                printMessage("Your guess number is less than lucky number")
            printAttempts(attempts)
            continue
            if (attempts == 0):
                printMessage("No attempts left, try again later")
                break
Button(root, text='Submit', width=20, bg='brown', fg='white',
       command=onSubmit).place(x=180, y=380)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When you enter a number and click `Submit` button, the while loop inside `onSubmit()` will decrease `attempts` to 0 and then exit.  So you can only see the result of the last iteration of the while loop after the function exits.

Comment: Everything after your `continue` will never execute.

Comment: remove the `while` loop....

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `while` loop fixes the problem.

1. Also have to make the `attempts` variable global.
2. Also have to modify the `if` statements.
3. Added some `print` statements for debugging.

comment:
prefer an alias `import tkinter as tk` to the wildcard `from tkinter import *`. it is easier to see where functions come from.

This works:

```py
import random
from tkinter import *

attempts = 3

random_number = random.randint(0, 999)

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
root.title("Number guessing game")
label_0 = Label(root, text="Number guessing game", width=20, font=("bold", 20))
label_0.place(x=90, y=53)

label_1 = Label(root, text="Enter number", width=20, font=("bold", 10))
label_1.place(x=80, y=150)
entry_1 = Entry(root)
entry_1.place(x=240, y=150)


def printAttempts(_attempts):
    attempt_string = "Attempt left: " + str(_attempts)
    label_attempt = Label(root,
                          text=attempt_string,
                          width=20,
                          font=("bold", 20))
    label_attempt.place(x=90, y=100)


printAttempts(3)


def printMessage(msg):
    _message = Label(root, text=msg, width=50, font=("bold", 10))
    _message.place(x=80, y=200)


def onSubmit():
    global attempts
    
    print('attempts', attempts)
    guessed_number = entry_1.get()
    guessed_number = int(guessed_number)

    if attempts != 0:
        print('the guess', guessed_number)
        print('the random', random_number)
        if (guessed_number == random_number):
            printMessage("Horray you just got it Right!")
            attempts = 0
            print(attempts)
        else:
            print('removing one attempt')
            attempts = attempts - 1
            printMessage("You got it wrong :(")
            if (guessed_number > random_number):
                printMessage("Your guess number is greater than lucky number")
                print('too high', attempts)
            else:
                printMessage("Your guess number is less than lucky number")
                print('too low', attempts)
            if (attempts == 0):
                printMessage("No attempts left, try again later")
                print('run out', attempts)
        printAttempts(attempts)            

Button(root, text='Submit', width=20, bg='brown', fg='white',
       command=onSubmit).place(x=180, y=380)

root.mainloop()
```

result:

[image]